# How to import CSV file into Excel with formatting

Tags: powershell, csv, excel-2010

I have a large CSV file from a server scan log and need to bring that into excel with formatting for certain criteria. Example being I need to filter only rows that have a status of severe and make a excel doc of those results. Very new to this process and how possibly writing a PowerShell script or excel template for the CSV files to do what I need works.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what your log file looks like it's really hard to give a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a CSV with the following table elements: Name, Domain, ID, and Status.

```
Import-CSV <path to csv> -header Name,Domain,ID,Status | ?{$_.Status -like "*severe*"} | Export-CSV <path to csv> -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```